# Co-op playlist of music?

Tags: webapp-rec, music

Anyone knows a website which can **play a list of songs** (like grooveshark), but also allows to **manage that playlist** by a predefined **group of people** by a some **cooperative** system (like voting)?

In my job, I like to listen music on the speakers but not everyone enjoys the same music, and I think we could use an application where every member of the team can introduce a song and/or vote on them.

I imagine the vote system being similar to reddit (or stackoverflow) in the way that every team member can vote up or down once for each song. And the most voted songs are played before the rest.

Is there a web site or any kind of application which can maintain a playlist by many people?

Comment: There is a nice thread on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/20803/intranet-music-web-application-for-an-office-media-server) that can help you

Comment: @Proton, did you found what you were looking for? I'm looking the same thing for my office, here in Tandil, Argentina.

Comment: @inakiabt, Nop. It seems that here in Argentina we like democracy to decide what music we listen at work. But we are out of luck.

Comment: A new app (Sep 2013) is http://lastset.io

Answer (score 1):

[Spotify](http://www.spotify.com) allow you to create collaborative playlists that several users can edit and reorder. Unfortunately I was unable to find a playlist voting system. It would be a really cool idea to implement.

Comment: Sadly I cannot access Spotify because they restrict access from most countries (I live in Argentina): http://www.spotify.com/int/why-not-available/

Comment: To share a playlist, click the "..." button to its right. Allegedly [Spotify also allows you to upload your own MP3s](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50452/17089).

Answer (score 0):

Neat concept, but no such system exists due to lack of a decent market size. Your best bet is to create a station on Pandora or related music service, and then seed the station with song / artist suggestions from the people in your office.

Answer (score 0):

Me and some friends started coding on such a web app. It's open source and any ideas and contributions are more than welcome. It's running live (but playback cannot be fully tested yet) here:

http://bip.bignetwork.se/

It's using the Spotify metadata API for finding songs, and will be using the libspotify api for playback on a central server. We built it in two parts, a webapp for voting and a daemon for playback.

The source code can be seen/cloned/forked from here: 
https://github.com/bignetwork/bip

Or check out our "spotify-daemon" repository for the playback daemon.

Ideas and issues can be added on Github.

It's currently in swedish but it uses I18N so it can easily be translated to more languages. I'd be happy to provide an english translation if there's an interest.

Comment: Interesting, but Bignetwork Internet Player uses Spotify which is not available in my country: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Availability_of_Spotify_in_the_World..svg

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jampri.com does exactly that. You sign in with Facebook connect and can create a playlist that only you and your friends can add songs to it. As the playlist creator you can decide which songs stay inside. You and everyone else can also vote on songs up/down etc. Try it out. Oh, it works with youTube videos so you find and add to playlist practically any song you can think of.

Comment: Nice! But sadly I'm not sure if it is what I asked for, because when I try to create a playlist it says: "Jampri is currently experiencing problems playing YouTube videos
We investigate this problem with YouTube to bring this problem to an end. Please bare with us, we will keep you posted very soon."... I guess I'll have to check it again in some time.

Comment: Jampri is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

[dj2q.com](http://www.dj2q.com) is a web app that uses YouTube for creative collaborative playlists. No log in required. Just type in a room name to enter or create. It should be available in all countries.

Comment: A promising prospect! Sadly it doesn't let me vote when I join to another's party (I can add new videos though).

Comment: There's so much wrong with this app! You can't skip to the next song. When searching, there's no information whatsoever as to where songs come from, what their duration or quality is, which makes it a shot in the dark to pick a version from the 20+ that appear for, e.g. "If I Rise ENiGMA Dubz Mix". You can't reorder songs. After a song is played, it disappears from the list. You can't save a list. Note that I've logged in, just in case, but no extra features become available.

Answer (score -1):

[Mixtape.me](http://mixtape.me) is pretty close but still no embedded voting or group management. I did recommend voting as a feature.

**EDIT:** Development has apparently ended. Too bad. This looked like a pretty sweet tool. To: Developer Adam Pash, I will give you fake internet points in exchange for countless hours of updating this app to make it awesome again.

Comment: Looks like development has ceased. I've also just got a Chrome malware alert after playing the first song there.

Answer (score -1):

Try [SongVote](http://www.songvote.com/songvote/index.jsp). A collaborative music + voting system.

Comment: Seems like a nice idea, although is not what I'm looking for. The more noticeable difference is that this web app doesn't actually reproduce the whole playlist (because you don't create a playlist, just songs to vote). And the really bad thing about this site is that doesn't work properly (I couldn't sing up after receiving an invite mail). And they don't care anymore probably as their contact mail is: user@email.com :(

Comment: "Down for maintenance" as of now.

Answer (score -1):

> [OUTLOUD.FM](http://outloud.fm) lets you create rooms where you can chat and listen to
>   music with your friends with a real time collaborative playlist. Just
>   sign in, pick a room name, and start uploading music!

and they've added [Soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com/) integration recently!

Comment: Outloud.FM is dead now.